# How can I search through an array using a limit on the number of digits considered?

Tags: swift, search, swift3

I have a function that searches a tuple of the format [(Double, Double)]. It finds a given x-value and if found, returns the corresponding y-value.

I need to alter it so that instead of searching for an exact x-value in the list of (x,y) pairs, it searches only up to the same number of digits after the decimal point of the given search term.

Example:

```
var a: [(Double, Double)] = [(0.0,0.0)]

a = [(0.1234, 0.0), (0.12345, 1.0), (0.123456, 2.0), (0.1234567, 3.0)]

//the current version of the function, this is what I need to change
func getValueFromTuples(tupleArr:[(Double,Double)],n:Double)->Double?{ 

    for tuple in tupleArr{

        if tuple.0 == n{

            return tuple.1

        }
    }

    return nil

}

print("Value:", getValueFromTuples(tupleArr: a, n: 0.1234)!)
//needs to return 0.0

print("Value:", getValueFromTuples(tupleArr: a, n: 0.12345)!)
//needs to return 1.0

print("Value:", getValueFromTuples(tupleArr: a, n: 0.123456)!)
//needs to return 2.0
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the posted code?

Comment: The problem is that if I search for the value `0.12`, nothing is returned. That's because `0.12` is not in the array. So I need the function to truncate the x-values in the array to the same number of decimal places as the input term. So every x-value will be truncated to `0.12` and then I only need to return the first y-value where there is a match.

Comment: Not related but why don't you use a – more convenient –  type like `CGPoint`?

Comment: So if the input is `0.12`, the function should return `0.0` because it is the first x-value that is a match. My code above currently does **not** do that, so I'd like some assistance in modifying it.

Comment: @vadian because I'm not sure how long it would take to adjust my project to work properly with `CGPoint` and I'm on a time limit.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the example you just described in your comment because as written, your code works for the 3 examples in your question.

Comment: @vadian The tuples are not points so using `CGPoint` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @rmaddy Hm, the OP is talking about x- and y-values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to convert each number to a string and see if the "x" string begins with the "n" string.

```
func getValueFromTuples(tupleArr: [(Double,Double)], n: Double) -> Double? {
    let nStr = "\(n)"
    for tuple in tupleArr {
        let xStr = "\(tuple.0)"
        if xStr.hasPrefix(nStr) {
            return tuple.1
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note that this really only works if the "x" values of your tuple array are sorted correctly.

Comment: Would this continue to search the rest of the array for other matching values? I need it to stop once it finds one value that matches.

Comment: Why would it continue? It has a `return` when a match is found. Try it. See what happens.

Comment: I assumed it might because it is for-looping through each value in `tupleArr`, so after it finds the first match it will go to the next value in `tupleArr` and do the same thing, no? New to Swift here.

Comment: Again, try it. Use the debugger and trace through the execution and see what happens. Great way to learn.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions. This lets people know the question is resolved. It also improves your reputation. You should go back and revisit your earlier questions and accept any answers you feel sufficiently answered the question.